# Failed to extract body.. Forbidden class

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm playing around with Camel & ActiveMQ trying to bounce around a dummy object between my queues. (No, wouldn't do that in a real case..)
However, I'm not allowed to do that with the security restrictions and I really can't figure out why?
I read about [objectmessage](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html) and I can see my changes in AMQ startup

> ..d:\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf\login.config -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=* -Dactivemq.classpath=d ..

And I added this in my connectionfactory

```
<property name="connectionFactory">
  <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

And my Dummy class implemenets Serializable.

Butit still refuses saying:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: 
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content.
Serializable class not available to broker. 
Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Forbidden class camelinaction.Dummy! This class is not trusted to be 
serialized as ObjectMessage payload.
```

I bet I forgot something simple.. but can't figure it out.

Cheers

Comment: Whatever the reason is, your `trustAllPackages` seems not to work. If you look at [this ActiveMQ client class](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.15.x/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java) starting from line 101, the error message you get is inside a check that `trustAllPackages` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Your setup look OK since you already allow serialization on broker and client.

The only thing I noticed is a small difference between your XML config and the one in the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html).

The docs use a classpath that contains a `spring` package. Your classpath is missing this package. Since the class in the `spring` package is a subclass of the class you use, it could make a difference, but it is just a wild guess.

```
class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope, it's there. As stated, it writes it out at startup
"-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*"

Comment: I edited my answer. You probably have to set it on the clients too.

Comment: Ok, but if you look at my question I have set "trustAllPackages" to true for the connectionfactory? That should do it as far as I understand?

Comment: Sorry, I answered based on the error message instead of your question. I once again edited my answer. The small difference is the only thing I can find.

Comment: I'll try that, there is something wrong with the trusting for sure

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I changed

```
java  -jar  -Xmx4096m  file.jar
```

to

```
java  -jar -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*  -Xmx4096m  file.jar
```

it worked for me

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].